# Grails Accessing secured directory with username/password

Tags: grails, file-permissions

Anyone tried accessing a secured folder on a shared drive using Grails? We have a Windows server where our Grails application needs to access a directory which is shared with just specific group of people.

I am getting a "access denied" when trying to access it with a `File` object

Need some way to pass the username/password.

["VFS"](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/api.html) will do the job in Java way, just wondering if there is any grails plugin or similar for this?

Comment: btw, Grails can use any JVM library, so you can use commons-vfs as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any grails VFS plugin to help you do this however; you can just add [commons-vfs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/api.html) as a dependency and mix groovy and java to accomplish this nicely.